# inline-block, italic text partially hides on Chrome with backface-visibility hidden

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I'm working on inline-block element animation with italic font-style. Just noticed an weird issue on chrome browser. The text partially hides when applies backface-visibility: hidden

to reproduce this issue.

```
font-style: italic;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I've made a little fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g817g9ph/3/

All other browser seems to work just fine. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `padding-right: 3px` to the `a.backface` solves this, however I don't know how this will affect the rest of your project.

```
a.backface {
    padding-right: 3px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g817g9ph/5/)

It seems like the `backface-visibility:hidden` acts a the same as `overflow:hidden`, since everything that doesn't fit in the original `div` is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that chrome is working properly here. The right hand part of the text is outside the bounding-box of the <a> (add a border and you will see) - so setting the backface-visibility to true in effect makes anything not on the front-face invisible ... so you loose the end of the text.

More info on the [MDN Page on backface-visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)

It does beg the question as to why you are using the experimental css rule and suggests that Rvervuurt's answer to add padding is a great way out.